# React and Vue cli returns bash: command not found

Tags: bash, reactjs, npm, vue.js, nodes

After successfully installing vue-cli, I can't run `vue init webpack my-project` command. It returns `bash: vue: command not found`.

And I tried react-cli, using `create-react-app project-name` and still returns `bash: create-react-app: command not found`

I already checked it using `npm list -g --depth=0` and it was installed in

```
C:\Users\userlocal\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- create-react-app@1.5.2
`-- vue-cli@2.9.3
```

My PC is running on `Windows7/Ultimate`, and I am using `node v8.9.4`, and `npm 5.8.0`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you are on windows, why are you using `bash` ? Are you using `cygwin` or something like that ?

Comment: No, I never use `cygwyn`. I used `git bash`. Is there something different when using `git bash` on windows?

Comment: Seems like neither `vue` nor `create-react-app` are on your `$PATH`. How did you install them on your system ?

Comment: I just followed their standard installation in their documentation.

`# install vue-cli
$ npm install --global vue-cli
# create a new project using the "webpack" template
$ vue init webpack my-project`

Comment: Type `env|grep PATH`. Are `vue` or `create-react-app` installed in the folders listed ? If not, you'll have to add their installation folders to your `$PATH`.

Comment: I typed `env|grep C:\Users\userlocal\AppData\Roaming\npm` and returns nothing. How to add their installation folders to my `$PATH`? Sorry, I'm just a beginner on using a terminal.

Comment: you need to type `env|grep PATH` (this exact command)

Comment: Sorry for that :)
Yes, here's the result:
`EXEPATH=C:\Users\rustonlocal\AppData\Local\Programs\Git
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ACLOCAL_PATH=/mingw64/share/aclocal:/usr/share/aclocal`

I cant paste the rest, it's too long

Comment: Do you have something like `PATH=C:\Users\bob\Documents\Whatever` ? Bash will only look for executables located in the folders refferenced by your `$PATH` variable.